# Error: Couldn't open stream with SDL 1.3

Tags: c, linux, sdl

I tried to run the following code with the SDL 1.3 library on Ubuntu Linux.
I got the following Error:

Error: Couldn't open stream
Error: Couldn't open stream

At

SDL_Init and SDL_CreateWindow

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if((SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0))
    {
        printf("[!] can't initialize SDL %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }


//    if((SDL_VideoInit(NULL) != 0))
//    {
//        printf("[!] can't initialize video %s\n", SDL_GetError());
//        exit(-1);
//    }

    SDL_Window* win;

    if(!(win = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL 1.3", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)))
    {
        printf("[!] can't create Window %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer. And now that you have tagged your question C, your code should be C. But I'm not aware of any `cstdlib` header in C. Also, I'd avoid sarcasm if I were you, asking for free help.

Answer (score 1):

I had no problems compiling your code on my Ubuntu box with:

```
gcc init.c -o init `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl`
```

And the output of **ldd** shows the application being linked with:

```
libSDL-1.3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.3.so.0 (0x00a94000)
```

When the application is executed, `Initializing touch...` is printed to the console. By the way, I downloaded and compiled SDL from sources.